# Does pg_dump preserve all Unicode characters when .sql file is ANSI?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I use

```
pg_dump.exe -U postgres -f "file-name.sql" database-name
```

to backup UTF-8 encoded databases on PostgreSQL 8.4 and 9.5, Windows host.  Some may have foreign characters such as Chinese, Thai etc stored in Characters columns.

The resulting .sql file shows **ANSI** encoding when opening in Notepad++ (I'm NOT applying ANSI to opened files by default).  How do I know if Unicode characters are always preserved in the dump file?  Should I be using an archive (object) backup file instead?

Comment: You should not use Postgres 8.4 any more. Upgrade **now**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html)

> By default, the dump is created in the database encoding.

There is no difference in a text file in ANSI encoding and UTF-8 if no extended characters are used. Maybe your dump has no special characters and thus the editor doesn't identify it as UTF-8.

If you want the SQL dump in a specific encoding, use the `--encoding=encoding` parameter or the `PGCLIENTENCODING` environment variable

Comment: For the OP's peace of mind it might be good to mention that PostgreSQL will error out if it cannot convert a character properly.

Comment: The string in DB is **เรียน พี่เจี๊ยบ ครับ**. In the ANSI .sql file this is represented as **à¹€à¸£à¸µà¸¢à¸™ à¸žà¸µà¹ˆà¹€à¸ˆà¸µà¹Šà¸¢à¸š à¸„à¸£à¸±à¸š**. I did use -E UTF8 which makes no difference either way.  Converting file to UTF8 encoding does preserve the characters you're right. Trying to wrap my head around all this...